# SCO Unix 3.2.2: sysadmsh issues

Tags: unix, terminal

When I type sysadmsh from the console prompt, it looks like this: 
[image: Shell]  The way it used to work is that the prompt would be in color and the lines would wrap correctly.

I've had a couple of issues with this system over the past year now, and I've been trying to migrate to something newer. A couple of months ago the 'termcap' file or something corrupted and this system hasn't worked right ever since.

Can someone please help? I've been able to recompile a termcap file from scratch and load it into an ansi terminal so that it's (somewhat) working, but I really need to be able to use sysadmsh and configure backups and such. (Oh, yeah, and the tape drive is broken too, but I'll make another post about that later)

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What is your TERM variable set to now?  I'll bet that if you define the appropriate value it might well work as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The term variable is set to ansi, but if I set it to anything else it either can't find the appropriate file in the strings.d folder or sysadmsh doesn't recognize it & nothing changes.